# How can I extend a java TimerTask in Jython and pass parameters to it?

Tags: java, jython, timertask, jython-2.5

I'm trying to extend a `TimerTask` in Jython to read data from some sensors, and then send that data through the network every one second.  In order to do that I need to pass the reader and server objects (as well as some event objects) to the `TimerTask` object.  When I try to do it through the `Timer.schedule` method I get this error:

```
File "C:\Documents\src\iButtonHandler.py", line 61, in run
TypeError: org.python.proxies.iButtonHandler$IButtonTimerTask$1(): expected 0 args; got 4
```

I gather that the `Timer.schedule` method calls the run method of the `TimerTaskObject`, but why doesn't it first call `__init__`?  I've also tried adding the parameters to my `TimerTask`'s `run` method, but I get the same thing.

Here's my code:

```
class IButtonTimerTask(TimerTask):

    def init(self, reader, server, enterPressed, runComplete):
        self.__reader = reader
        self.__server = server
        self.__enterPressed = enterPressed
        self.__runComplete = runComplete

    def run(self):
        iButtonData = self.__reader.getAllValues()
        self.__server.sendData(iButtonData):
        if self.__enterPressed.isSet():
            self.cancel()
            self.__runComplete.set()

class IButtonHandler(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, port, container, enterPressedEvent, exitEvent):

        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name='iButton Handler Thread')
        print 'creating ibutton thread'
        self.__container = container
        self.__reader = IButtonContainerReader(self.__container)
        self.__containerId = self.__reader.getID()
        self.__server = MyServer(port, name=self.__containerId)
        self.__enterPressed = enterPressedEvent
        self.__exitEvent = exitEvent
        self.__runComplete = threading.Event()
        self.start()


    def run(self):
        print 'ibutton thread running'
        if self.__server.listen():
            timer = Timer()
            timer.schedule(IButtonTimerTask(self.__reader, self.__server, self.__enterPressed, self.__runComplete), 0, 1000)

        self.__runComplete.wait()
            print 'iButton handler %s exiting' %self.__containerId
            timer.cancel()
            self.shutDown()
            return
```

I see that in straight Java you simply extend `TimerTask` and call `new MyTimerTask(...)` in the `Timer.schedule` method.  I can't seem to make it work that way in Jython.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for taking a look at this!

Comment: I was also thinking that maybe I could create the TimerTask as an inner class of the IButtonHandler in order to have access to the IButtonHandler's variables.  I think that the self.__ would cause a problem though, and I'm not really sure how jython inner classes work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `init` should be called `__init__`:

```
class IButtonTimerTask(TimerTask):

    def __init__(self, reader, server, enterPressed, runComplete):
        ^^    ^^
```

Comment: I'd love to upvote you, but I don't have enough reputation to do so.  I probably won't earn any by making this kind of mistake...